# .NET MAUI Blazor credential autofill

Tags: blazor, maui, credentials, autofill, maui-blazor

We have .NET MAUI Blazor app (Android, iOS, Windows) which contains a login form with 2 inputs:

```
<input name="username" type="text" autocomplete="username" />
<input name="password" type="password" autocomplete="current-password" />
```

But even though we have `autocomplete` specified in those inputs, they don't provide any hints.

I read many articles and I also found [XAML-related](https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/Maui/issues/373) issue, but nothing for this Blazor use-case. Do you know what is required to make this work ?

Comment: Even with the fixed typo it doesn't work

Comment: What does "provide any hints" mean to you - what are you expecting?

Comment: I expect it to pre-fill these fields with latest credentials, or show a password manager popup.

Comment: For this, you can check this thread: [Maui Blazor input dropdown list not accepting input value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75558144/maui-blazor-input-dropdown-list-not-accepting-input-value) .